# Error trying to add a Discord.js random variable inside the Embed Field

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content === '!s') {

var answers = [
    '"Title field" , "Inline Field",'

]

var randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("This is your title")
  .setAuthor("Author Name")
  .setColor(0x00AE86)
  .setDescription("This is the main body of text, it can hold 2048 characters.")
  .addField(randomAnswer)
 
  message.channel.send({embed});


}


});
```

I am trying to insert a random variable from an array into the Discord.JS Embed ".addField()" however no matter what I do I still cant seem to get it working.

I am using discord.js 12v.

Comment: Hey there! It is hard to find out what is wrong with your code if you don't include the error messages. Please include these and also describe what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Add Field Takes 3 Parameters Not just 1.

**EDIT**

> Another error you made is passing a non string value into `.setColor()`. It should Instead be `.setColor('0x00AE86')`

**addField() Syntax**

```
.addField(<Title>, <Content>, <InlineBool>)
```

What you're looking for is

```
.addField('Some Title', randomAnswer, false)
// ...
message.channel.send(embed)
```

Learn about `.addField()` and other embed methods [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)

Comment: Note that the third parameter is optional and defaults to `false`